Issues with surge protector for home office / media setup
For a while I have used a Belkin 8 way surge protector on a home office setup.
However, I have had regular problems with the single switch appearing to spark when turned on, failing to turn off properly (as if it would physically not return back to the off position) and failing long before it is due to do so according to the claims on the box.
I am not sure what is causing this but suspect it is an issue with load on the switch, and was wondering about getting a proper PDU to deal with it, such as this high end power strip type but it seems to lack surge protection - can that be added?
There is a surge protected version but that seems to have the same issue with having a single switch. Will either of these help or is there likely to be some other fault?

What switch? Is this a toggle switch on the Belkin, a networking switch, some other component? Your question needs further information, but also load doesn't cause sparks in my experience: Whatever that switch is is likely faulty and further use WILL damage other components connected or impacted by it as a spark is an uncontrolled electrical pulse moving places it ought not be.

If its physically not moving then its faulty.
Sparking can happen for many reasons such as

if the load (whats connected to it) is too high.
if the switch is bouncing (connecting and disconnecting several times a second)
The metal on the switch contacts has already eroded and there is not enough for the current passing through it.
etc

Check the load on that switch and either measure it or calculate it.  If possible, split it in two.  You need to do this before you invest in another strip.
